# How to get value from Json using groovy script

Tags: groovy

Hi I am new to groovy and API Automation. I have the following Json and i want to add assertion to check  cyclestartdate and cycleEnddate based on sequence number.

```
{
   "status" : "success",
   "locale" : "",
   "data" : {
      "periods" : [
         {
            "payCycleId" : "custompayperiod",
            "sequence" : 1,
            "cycleStartDate" : "2018-10-01",
            "cycleEndDate" : "2018-10-08"
         },
         {
            "payCycleId" : "custompayperiod",
            "sequence" : 2,
            "cycleStartDate" : "2018-10-09",
            "cycleEndDate" : "2018-10-16"
         }
      ]
   }
}
```

How do i check if sequence 1 cycleStartDate is 2018-10-01

Answer (score 3):

Groovy provides [`JsonSlurper`](http://groovy-lang.org/json.html) class that makes parsing JSON documents easier. Consider following example that reads JSON document as a `String` (it supports different initialization methods as well):

```
import groovy.json.JsonSlurper

def inputJson = '''{
   "status" : "success",
   "locale" : "",
   "data" : {
      "periods" : [
         {
            "payCycleId" : "custompayperiod",
            "sequence" : 1,
            "cycleStartDate" : "2018-10-01",
            "cycleEndDate" : "2018-10-08"
         },
         {
            "payCycleId" : "custompayperiod",
            "sequence" : 2,
            "cycleStartDate" : "2018-10-09",
            "cycleEndDate" : "2018-10-16"
         }
      ]
   }
}'''

def json = new JsonSlurper().parseText(inputJson)

assert json.data.periods.find { it.sequence == 1 }.cycleStartDate == '2018-10-01'
```

Having JSON document loaded you can extract data by accessing nested fields. For instance, `json.data.periods` gives you an access to the array stored in your JSON document. Then method `find { it.sequence == 1 }` returns a node from this array where `sequence` field is equal to `1`. And lastly you can extract `cycleStartDate` and compare it with the expected date.

> You can find more useful examples in [Groovy's official documentation](http://groovy-lang.org/json.html).

Comment: thanks alot , it did work. Since i have less than 15 reputation i can't cast you vote, but will do once i get it. Thanks once again

Comment: @syednaveed, even you can't vote, however you can stall accept the answer.